# Detect if row is selected on InitializeRow event

Tags: c#, infragistics

I have an `ultrawingrid` filled with contacts - some of which need to appear in a different colour scheme based on that contact's attributes.

I have an `initializerow` event, with the following simple code:

```
    private void grdPeople_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells["NoSMS"].Value != null)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells["NoSMS"].Value.ToString() == "True")
            {
                e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 80, 50, 30);
                e.Row.Appearance.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 150, 150, 150);
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above greys-out a contact if they have a `NoSMS` flag set to true - meaning they do not wish to be contacted. Respecting privacy etc etc.

Now, when that row is selected, this colour is overriden by the 'selected' colour scheme of the `ultrawingrid` - meaning that when the user is selected a large group of contacts, it is not immediately visible which ones are 'greyed-out'.

I have tried adding the following code but it has not worked:

```
                foreach (UltraGridRow row in grdPeople.Selected.Rows)
                {
                    if (e.Row.Index == row.Index)
                    {
                        e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 80, 50, 30);
                        e.Row.Appearance.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 150, 150, 150);
                    }
                }
```

Does anyone know how I might detect if the current row being initialized is currently in a selection, or why that code may not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to do is to define the `Appearance` just one time through the designer and adding it to the `Appearances` collection of the `DisplayLayout` property.
Every `Appearance` stored there is identified by a key value (let's use "disabled_row" for this scenario).

In this way you have just one appearance and not one appearance per row.
Also referencing the cell value in that way could cause a lot of memory consumption, the recommended way by Infragistics is to retrieve the value using the `GetCellValue` method ([See WinGrid Performance Guide](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/15306.aspx))

Then your code in the `InitializeRow` could be changed to

```
private void grdPeople_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    UltraGridColumn c = e.Row.Band.Columns["NoSMS"];
    object o = e.Row.GetCellValue(c) ?? false;
    bool noSMS = Convert.ToBoolean(o);

    if (noSMS)
    {
        e.Row.Appearance = grdPeople.DisplayLayout.Appearances["disabled_row"];
        foreach(UltraGridCell c in e.Row.Cells)
            c.SelectedAppearance = grdPeople.DisplayLayout.Appearances["disabled_row"];
    }
}
```

Check also the [Conditional Formatting](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/) on the Infragistics help pages (but this works only cell by cell AFAIK)

Comment: In the `initializeRow` function, there is no definition for `e.Layout.Appearances` :(

Comment: right, too fast typing without checking, however the collection of Appearances could be retrieved directly from the grid.DisplayLayout property. Answer updated

Comment: Thanks for the help steve. What is `r` in this context?

Comment: I suppose that this is a good signal to stop for today. Fixed